# Как объединить скрипт меню и ajax js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть скрипт меню http://jsfiddle.net/htyxud07/1/ нужно добавить `ajax` запрос, чтобы после клика на меню, открывалось окно и `ajax`-ом загружались данные данной категории.

скрипт меню js:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      var $box = $('.box');
      $('.metro li').each(function(){
        var color = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
        var content = $(this).html();
        $(this).click(function() {
        $box.css('backgroundColor', color);
        $box.addClass('open');
        $box.find('p').html(content);
      });

      $('.close').click(function() {
        $box.removeClass('open');
        $box.css('backgroundColor', 'transparent');
      });   
     }); 
    });
```

Ajax:

```
$(".ajax_but").click(function() {
    //var id = $(this).attr("id");
    //var data_ajax = 'id='+ id ;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: data_ajax,
        cache: false,
        success: function(res){
          $("#id_ajax").html(res);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: А что именно у вас не получается сделать? Что конкретно не работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение данного вопроса, добавил к меню `data-id`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $box = $('.box');
  $('.metro li').each(function(){
    var color = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
    var content = $(this).html();
    $(this).click(function() {
    $box.css('backgroundColor', color);
    $box.addClass('open');
    var id_click = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var data_ajax = 'id='+ id_click ;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: data_ajax,
        cache: false,
        success: function(res){
          $box.find('p').html(res);
        }
    });     
  });   
  $('.close').click(function() {
    $box.removeClass('open');
    $box.css('backgroundColor', 'transparent');
  });   
 }); 
});
```